# Hibernate Transaction: Only Last item of list is saved into the table

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb

I have a list of DTO classes which need to be save into database table. Only last item is being saved into the database due to some unknown reason which I am not able to tracked.

Find below the sample service and manager class,

```
class TestService {

public void saveData(List<OrderDTO> dtolist) {
//exception handling properly
transaction.begin();
manager.saveAlldata(dtolist);
transaction.commit();
}
}

Class TestManager {
 public void saveAlldata(List<OrderDTO> dtolist) {
//exception handles properly
 for(OrderDTO dto: dtolist){
    OrderPersist persist = new OrderPersistent();
    persist.setId(dto.getId());
    persist.setItem(dto.getItem());
 //save(persist) or merge(persist);
  }
}
```

Assume I have 2 item details e.g. id=1, Item=S_001 and Id=2, Item=S_002 in the dto list then only last item (2, S_002) is being saved into the table.

Answer (score 1):

Have u tried this?

```
public void saveAlldata(List<OrderDTO> dtolist) {
//exception handles properly
 for(OrderDTO dto: dtolist){
transaction.begin();
OrderPersist persist = new OrderPersistent();
persist.setId(dto.getId());
persist.setItem(dto.getItem());
//save(persist) or merge(persist);
transaction.commit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `session.save` inside the for loop.

```
 for(OrderDTO dto: dtolist){
    OrderPersist persist = new OrderPersistent();
    persist.setId(dto.getId());
    persist.setItem(dto.getItem());
    session.save(persist);
 }
```

Also consider keeping a count of the save and can use a counter. Something like the following:

```
if( i % 50 == 0 ) {
  session.flush();
  session.clear();
}
```

where i is the count.

Comment: This first part is the same as you explained, Save = session.Save(), merge=entityManager.merge();
will try the second part